# Jquery Hide show toggle on DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Apparently my toggle function does not work. I need to Hide a div "photography" when clicking the word "photography" that is located in another div. Please see my code below

HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
        <div="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
            <a href="#"  id="hideshow" class="btn">Photography</a>
            <a href="#"  id="hideshow" class="btn">Graphics</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <section id="photograhpy" class="photograhpy">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">

                    <hr class="small">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="photograhpy-item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="img-photograhpy img-responsive" src="imgs/pics/car1.jpg">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hideshow").click(function(){
    $("#photography").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a spelling error:

```
 <section id="photograhpy" class="photograhpy">
```

Should be:

```
 <section id="photography" class="photography">
```

There is nothing else outstandingly wrong with your code.

Also, you may not reference elements with the same id exclusively via JavaScript. It is poor practice to give multiple elements the same id.

Comment: Please also state that it is bad to use the same id for multiple elements. He is doing so for `hideshow`

Comment: Except for that, that is also very bad, thanks I did not notice.

Comment: Thank you so much. that was a bit funny for the reason. I apologize, I'm just starting with all of this especially js. and also I have noted your tip. id's are now different. thanks again! –